# Pull in Directions API response object to the map?

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, reactjs

I've used GoogleMaps api to return a routes/directions object to get from A to B. And react-google-maps to render the map. These are separate API's though.

How do I pass the *route* from the directions API... to the map from the maps api - so I can draw the red-line that illustrates the route?

I was thinking r/g/m might have a prop you can use like `directions={api.response.routesArrayHere}` but i'm drawing blanks with it.

API response:[image: api response directions array]

react-google-maps:

```
import React from 'react';
import { GoogleMapLoader, GoogleMap, Marker } from 'react-google-maps';

class Map extends React.Component {
  render() {

    const mapContainer = <div style={{height: '100%', width: '100%', border: '5px solid black', borderColor: 'rgba(4, 3, 75, 0.3)'}}></div>;

    const markers = this.props.markers.map((yourLocation, i) => {
      const marker = {
        position: {
          lat: yourLocation.location.lat,
          lng: yourLocation.location.lng
        }
      };

      return <Marker key={i} {...marker} />;
    });
    return (
    <GoogleMapLoader
      containerElement = {mapContainer}
      googleMapElement = {
          <GoogleMap
              defaultZoom={10}
              defaultCenter={this.props.center}
              options={{streetViewControl: false, mapTypeControl: false}}>
              {markers}
          </GoogleMap>
      } />

    );
  }
}

Map.propTypes = {
  center: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  markers: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

export default Map;
```

Comment: You can do it simply as native js, create DirectionService, set map via refs, and after that render directions on them.

Comment: Thanks @DmitriyKovalenko - not sure i understand. You mean where props sit within the GoogleMap component? That's where the DirectionsRenderer class would sit?